# Get JSON object value using JS code in Zapier

Tags: javascript, json, zapier, webflow

Can somebody tell me how to get the productName out of the "step 1" output to the right, using JS code. I believe that the output from step 1 is an JSON object.

Or are there any easier ways doing this?

Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work for you. Although dealing with the lines containing objects may require more.

```
var lines = inputData.productName.split("\n");
var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  var pair = lines[i].split(":");
  obj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}
return obj;
```